# getting error Received unregistered task of type 'mytasks.add'

Tags: redis, celery

I have written a file `mytasks.py`

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery("tasks",
                broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
                backend='redis')


@celery.task
def add(x,y):
        return x+y
```

and `task.py` as follow

```
from mytasks import add

add.delay(1,1)
```

I have started redis server and I have started celery server. but when i m running task.py then i am getting the following error:

```
    Received unregistered task of type 'mytasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'mytasks.add', 'eta': None, 'args': (1, 1), 'expires': None, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': 'a4792308-d575-4de4-8b67-26982cae2fa4', 'utc': True} (173b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 411, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body, message.ack_log_error)
KeyError: 'mytasks.add'
```

what may be the possibel reason

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hey I have solved the  problem 
i did one thing i add

```
CELERY_IMPORTS=("mytasks")
```

in my `celeryconfig.py` file and i got succeed.

Answer (score 2):

also can use `include` param in Celery class: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#proj-celery-py